# Synchronize model in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, synchronization, data-modeling, mysql-workbench

After reading the documentation for MySQL Workbench I got the impression that it's possible to alter a database in the server (e.g. add a new column) and later incorporate the DDL changes into your EER diagram. At least, it has a *Synchronize Model* option in the *Database* menu. I found it a nice feature because I could use a graphic modelling tool without becoming its prisoner.

In practice, when I run such tool I'm offered these options:

```
Model             Update  Source
================  ======  ======
my_database_name  -->     ! N/A
   my_table_name  -->     ! N/A
N/A               -->     ! my_database_name
   N/A            -->     ! my_table_name
```

I can't really understand it, but leaving it as is I basically get:

```
DROP SCHEMA my_database_name
CREATE SCHEMA my_database_name
CREATE TABLE my_table_name
```

This is a dump of the model that overwrites all remote changes in my_table_name.

Am I misunderstanding the feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly? I think it's a bug.  I've run into the same problem on several occasions and I'm not sure what the issue is.

I suggest checking the [bug repository](http://bugs.mysql.com/) and, if you don't find anything, reporting this as a new one.

Comment: I can confirm it's a bug. I played around with the model, renaming the schema and adding new tables, and suddenly the synchronization feature was working as advertised: I could easily merge into my model a column that had been added outside.

It's going to be a fantastic tool if it ever gets out of alpha :)

Comment: The bug is the 45533 ... http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=45533&edit=3 don't use caps or underscore in the name of the database

Comment: I do agree with above comment. It is bug and don't use caps letter or underscore in database or table name/schema.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the real bug that you can follow. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61211 And there is a workaround from one of the mysql QA people:

A workaround is to open the Scripting Shell, inspect the name of the schema and make
sure that the oldName field contains the same name as what you're trying to synchronize
against. 
Commands for that are:

```
# print current oldName value
print grt.root.wb.doc.physicalModels[0].catalog.schemata[0].oldName
# change the oldName field value
grt.root.wb.doc.physicalModels[0].catalog.schemata[0].oldName = "newname"
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this bug was fixed on around "27 July 2012" so it should not be a problem for most users today.

Answer (score 1):

I always use the synchronization *successful* several times! But today I have the same problem - and wonder way?

So I study the BUG-Report by MySQL and find the problem...

### Don't use caps or underscore in the name of the database

So I am:

- rename my database,
- change the name of the model in the "Model Overview"
- and  change the name of the Default Schema, use in the "Connection Options".

And it works! ... now I have to change the name of the database in the applicationconfig ...